# Is there any way to remove delivered notifications upon arrival of a new one? react-native-push-notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native

My scenario is I just want to remove the delivered notifications when the new notification arrives. Is there any way to do that using react-native-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
PushNotification.configure({
  onNotification: function () {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    // or if you want to cancel only by id:
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: '123'});
  },
}
```

I think this is only going to work if the app is in background or in foreground.

Comment: The thing is, onNotification not calling when notification generates

Comment: You can try using the same id or same tag